# React JSX is missing in Webstorm language. What should I do?

Tags: jsx

[image]

As you can see in the picture, it shows that there is a problem with all the lines.

So I tried to change the language, but React JSX is not in the drop-down.

[image]

Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EcmaScript6+ should contain JSX support but it does not work on opening already existing projects. Only when you create a new React project JSX works as expected.